# What does locationInView: mean for a multi-finger gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and in the target method have this code:

```
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
    CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
    CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

    piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
    piece.center = locationInSuperview;
}
```

But I'm not quite understanding which value the `locationInView:` return value indicates, because there are supposed to be two fingers touching the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `locationInView:` method returns the center point of both touches. If you want to know the positions of the two individual touches, use `locationOfTouch:inView:`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation is a good idea:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It is the "centroid" of the multiple touches.